# Command not found in zsh

Tags: shell, zsh, command-not-found

In bash, whenever I try to run a command which is not installed, I get a message which tells that the package is not installed and how to install it. This functionality is provided by installing the Debian/Ubuntu package `command-not-found`. But in zsh, it only gives the message `command not found`. So how do I install this feature in zsh?

[image: error in zsh]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As long as you have the `command-not-found` package installed, all you should need to do is source the zsh config for that package by adding the following line to your `~/.zshrc`, and then opening a new shell (or running `. ~/.zshrc` in any existing ones):

```
[[ -r /etc/zsh_command_not_found ]] && . /etc/zsh_command_not_found
```

Comment: Unfortunately this removes the 'command not found' message when alternatives aren't found. This seems like a bug. Replacing the command-not-found call with `/usr/lib/command-not-found ${1}` fixes that problem.